# strange error when passing argumento to bash script

Tags: bash, scripting

I am not expert of bash scripting, but I really don't understand what is appening here. My script is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "calling asetup"
export ATLAS_LOCAL_ROOT_BASE=/cvmfs/atlas.cern.ch/repo/ATLASLocalRootBase
source ${ATLAS_LOCAL_ROOT_BASE}/user/atlasLocalSetup.sh
asetup 17.6.0,slc5

echo "Now running..."
echo "argument $@"
```

I call it with as `./myscript -v`, the output is:

```
calling asetup
atlasLocalSetup.sh: invalid option -- 'v'
'atlasLocalSetup.sh --help' for more information
./prova.sh: line 12: asetup: command not found
Now running...
argument -v
```

on the second line, what is `atlasLocalSetup.sh: invalid option -- 'v'`?? Why is`atlasLocalSetup.sh` called with the `-v` option?

Answer (score 3):

The sourced script is run in the current environment without changing the value of positional parameters. The value of "$@" is the same for the called script as for the calling script.

You can use

```
set --
```

to clear the positional parameters. If you need to save them, use

```
pos_par=("$@")
set --
source script.sh
set -- "${pos_par[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are calling your script file with a `-v` option. Note that `source` does not change the values of the commandline parameters (`$1`) unless positional parameters are provided to the `source` command.